# Javascript / Angular - html displays before rendering code

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a function to get rates from products, so lets say I have one product with two rates. So my product has two rates. Then, when I get those rates I must get the prices attached to my product. So for each rate I have to look for its prices.

The next code below explains this:

```
this.loadProductInfo = true; // bool to load data in my form

// First of all, I get rates from API
// const rates = this._http....
// Now, for each rate I must search If my product/products have a price:

this.rates.forEach((rate, index, arr) => {
   this._glbGetPricesForProduct.getPrice(params).subscribe(response => {
      if (!arr[index + 1]) {
        this.initForm();
        this.loadProductInfo = false;
      } 
   })
});
```

The variable loadProductInfo it loads content in my form, so in my html I have:

```
<form *ngIf="!loadProductInfo"></form>
```

But form it still give me error: could not find control name.

But if I do this instead, it works correctlly:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.initForm();
    this.loadProductInfo = false;
}, 2000);
```

So what I want its to say my form to wait until I have all code loaded and then after it, load its contents. But instead it cant find the control because it loads before code. Any help I really appreciate it.

Comment: why did you call `this._glbGetPricesForProduct.getPrice(params)` in your forEach loop if you don't use any data from your rates ? What is the value of your params variable ?

Comment: thats a call to api to get prices based on the product and rate, it gives you and array of prices, it does not matter really, I just want to know why form loads before I end my observable in the last iteration of the foreach. Because I have to set a timeout to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main mistake I see there is that you are looping over async data which may not be there when your code execute the for each loop (your rates).
I would build an observable with your rates as a source:

```js
...
$rates: Observable<any> = this._http.get(...);
rates.pipe(
    mergeMap((rates) => {
        const priceByRates: Observable<any>[] = rates.map((rate, index, arr) => this._glbGetPricesForProduct.getPrice(params));
        return combineLatest(pricesByRates); // if getPrice complete right away, use forkJoin() instead
    })
).subscribe(res => {
    // No need to check for the last item, all rates have been checked for possible price
    this.initForm();
    this.loadProductInfo = false; 
});
...
```

This implementation should wait for your api calls to resolve before printing your form.

Comment: I use this: if (!res[index + 1]).... to check when its the last iteration in forEach, so when I get the last one, i use my bool to load my form

Comment: What you have written there means: "if the next index is undefined". To check for the last item, you should write: if (index === arr.length - 1). But with what I wrote in my answer, you don't even need that. Once it has emitted, it means it has processed all the array.

Comment: perfect, thank you so much, I should learn about rxjs

Answer (score 0):

Since you are hiding the entire form, it may be better to just move the API call into a resolver so that the page does not render until the data is ready.

Here is a minimal StackBlitz showcasing this behavior: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4beuww

### Component

In your component, include an ActivatedRoute parameter via DI.

```js
@Component(/*omitted for brevity*/)
export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    // note: 'data' is whatever you label your resolver prop in your routing setup
    route.data.subscribe(resolved => {
      if ("data" in resolved) this.resolveData = resolved["data"];
    });
  }
}
```

### Route Setup

And in your router setup you would have the following:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'my-route-path',
    component: MyComponent,
    resolve: {
      data: MyResolver
    }
  }
];
```

### Resolver

Finally, your resolver would make your API call utilizing your service:

```js
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyResolver() implements Resolve<T> {

  constructor(private service: MyService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<T> | Promise<T> | any {
    return this.service.myRequest();
  }
}
```

The final result will be that your view will not be rendered until your data is ready.